# Reinventing a typical 'Get nearest enum value' function to include flag combinations

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums

#### SCENARIO

I'm working with an `Enum` with `FlagsAttribute` set, for this question I will give as example the `System.IO.FileAttributes` enumeration.

Giving a value, I would like to get the nearest value in the `Enum` including the flag combinations.

For example giving a value of **10**, the nearest value in the enum above is **4** which is `FileAttributes.System`.

But if we include the flag combinations then the nearest value should be **7**, which is `FileAttributes.ReadOnly, FileAttributes.Hidden, FileAttributes.System`.

#### QUESTION

I don't pretend to reinvent the wheel, I just would like to improve this to take in consideration the possible flag combinations.

Then, in C# or VB.Net, how I could write a kind of '**Get nearest enum flags-combination**' function?

#### CODE

This is what I normally use to get the nearest value of an `Enum`, this does not take in consideration the flag combinations.

I've written this function expecting that this works for short/ushort/integer/uinteger/long/ulong enumerations but by the moment I didn't tested it in all scenarios.

VB.Net:

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the nearest value of an <see cref="T:Enum"/>.
''' </summary>
Private Function GetNearestEnumValue(Of T)(ByVal value As Long) As T
    Return (From enumValue As T
            In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T)).Cast(Of T)()
            Order By Math.Abs(value - Convert.ToInt64(enumValue))
            ).First
End Function
```

C# online translation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the nearest value of an <see cref="T:Enum"/>.
/// </summary>
private T GetNearestEnumValue<T>(long value)
{

    return (from enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>()orderby Math.Abs(value - Convert.ToInt64(enumValue))).First;

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//=======================================================
```

Comment: Where does 10 come from that you want to use it as a FileAttr but it doesnt already represent the actual flag combo?

Comment: The `10` is the imaginary value passed to the function hat I would like to do: `GetNearestValue(Of FileAttributes)(10)`

Comment: Any particular reason to include an automated C# translation here? That seems ... out of place.

Comment: The question is tagged as C# and Vb.Net, so it does not seems to be out of place since a good question has to demonstrate the progress done giving a code example in the specified language, then there is the code example. Also, many people downvotes or discrminates a VB question tagged with C# only because they doesn't udnerstand that an Vb.Net question has something to do with C#, then the code example is also to avoid those people reasoning. sorry for my english.

Comment: I know how functions work.  Let me ask a different way: what would the desired answer be for a value of 8202?

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you are trying to ask me, but giving a `8202`, the resulting nearest value should be `8199`, which is this flag combination: `ReadOnly, Hidden, System, NotContentIndexed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be other ways to do this but here's one possible solution.

Start with the underlying value of the flags enum (eg. Int32) and loop backwards. Once you hit a valid flag, store it. Do the same again but this time loop forward. Then you simply check which one is nearest. I've only implemented the signed integer part, so I leave the unsigned part for you to finish.

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module EnumExtension

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetNearest(Of TEnum As Structure)(ByVal flags As TEnum) As TEnum

        'Get the enum type
        Dim enumType As Type = GetType(TEnum)

        'If it's not an enum, throw(up)
        If (Not enumType.IsEnum) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException()
        End If

        'Check if the underlying type of the enum is a 8|16|32|64 bit signed integer:
        If ({GetType(SByte), GetType(Int16), GetType(Int32), GetType(Int64)}.Contains(enumType.GetEnumUnderlyingType())) Then

            'Cast the flags
            Dim value As Int64 = CType(CType(flags, Object), Int64)

            'Get all enum flags
            Dim enumValues As IEnumerable(Of Int64) = (From item In [Enum].GetValues(enumType) Select CType(item, Int64))

            'Get the minimum flag value.
            Dim minSum As Int64 = (From item In enumValues Order By item Ascending Select item).First()

            'Sum all flags to get the highest possible value.
            Dim maxSum As Int64 = enumValues.Sum()

            '..
            Dim lowerValue As Int64
            Dim higherValue As Int64
            Dim tempValue As TEnum = Nothing

            'Get the nearest lower value
            For lowerValue = value To minSum Step -1L
                tempValue = CType([Enum].ToObject(enumType, lowerValue), TEnum)
                If (tempValue.ToString() <> lowerValue.ToString()) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            'Get the nearest higher value
            For higherValue = value To maxSum Step +1L
                tempValue = CType([Enum].ToObject(enumType, higherValue), TEnum)
                If (tempValue.ToString() <> higherValue.ToString()) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("value: {0}, lower: {1}, higher: {2}", value, lowerValue, higherValue))

            'Return the nearest value.
            If ((value - lowerValue) <= (higherValue - value)) Then
                Return CType([Enum].ToObject(enumType, lowerValue), TEnum)
            Else
                Return CType([Enum].ToObject(enumType, higherValue), TEnum)
            End If

        Else 'If 8|16|32|64 bit unsigned integer aka. (Byte, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64)

            'Todo: work

        End If

    End Function


End Module
```

Test:

```vb
Dim value As FileAttributes = CType(8202, FileAttributes)
Dim nearest As FileAttributes = value.GetNearest()

Debug.WriteLine("value: {0}, flags: {1}", CType(nearest, Integer), nearest.ToString())
```

Output:

> value: 8202, lower: 8199, higher: 8208
>   value: 8199, flags: ReadOnly, Hidden, System, NotContentIndexed